# Cocos2d-X Loading OBB / Expansion Files

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, apk-expansion-files

My Cocos2d-X game is larger than 50 Mo so as I read on the Android documentation I have to use expansion files.
I followed this subject: [Android OBB/ZIP loading (cocos2dx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573096/android-obb-zip-loading-cocos2dx)
So I modified Cocos2dxHelper.java and placed my OBB file (a renamed Zip file) on my device's sdcard: /Android/obb/com.project.id/com.project.id.obb
Unfortunately my OBB file is not loaded.
I added theses permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Where is my mistake?
Did you succeeded with loading assets from an OBB file?
Is there something else to do?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here is the fullpath of my OBB File: /sdcard/emulated/0/com.emedion.games.bardadum/main.1.com.emedion.games.bardadum.obb
I read that "/sdcard/emulated/0/" is the correct external storage path since Android 4.2.

I'm testing it on a Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Could you post the name of the obb file that you placed and the path to it? I also followed the tutorial that you linked, and I had no problems with it.

Comment: @Losiowaty I updated my post to mention it.

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, but this path may vary by device vendor and you propably want to target your game for more devices than just 4.2+. Try replacing the hardcoded path with `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Comment: That's exactly what I used

Comment: Ok, so could you post the changes you made to `Cocos2dxHelper.java`. Also, just in case, did you rebuild the library? The best courrse would be to clean both cocos2dx-lib and your project, then build them one by one.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573096/android-obb-zip-loading-cocos2dx][1]

try Answer 2 it work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've downloaded the latest release of Cocos2d-x (v2.2.1), made the modifications mentionned in the thread I mentionned ([Android OBB/ZIP loading (cocos2dx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573096/android-obb-zip-loading-cocos2dx)) and it work. I've created a new project and just zipped resources without any code modification.
I think the problem was coming from compilation caching or something like that now I have to make my project working.

Thanks for your help.