# How to load directly obb in cocos2dx v 2.1.4

Tags: cocos2d-x

I'm working on Cocos2dx project and facing with a problem!
In cocos2dx, i can change data in assets folder to another path and my app can load texture and sound successfully.

This is my code in `CCFileUtilsAndroid.cpp`. It's work ok

```
bool CCFileUtilsAndroid::init()
{
    m_strDefaultResRootPath = "/mnt/sdcard/Testing/";
    return CCFileUtils::init();
}
```

But I want to read directly obb file without unzip it. I had to set this line into Cocos2dxHelper.java at init function.

```
Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetApkPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/obb/com.example.test/Testing.obb");
```

But it's fail to load anything in obb file.

I read some solution in stackoverflow same as: 
[Android OBB/ZIP loading (cocos2dx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573096/android-obb-zip-loading-cocos2dx)

But i can't find solution for me. 
Please help me for this issue! Hope your reply! 
Thanks you very much

Comment: You really need to provide more information.You aren't saying anything about thrown errors, etc.

Comment: I looked at this again and you wording of 'read directly obb file without unzip it' is confusing. You dont have to unzip it yourself, cocos2d-x had a function`getFileDataFromZip()` that would do the heavy lifting

Comment: Hi, I try to use getFileDataFromZip but i'm failure.
I just want to load obb in cocos2dx. Do you have any solution or example code. Hope your help!

Comment: Hi, i finished to load obb file!
I used solution with 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573096/android-obb-zip-loading-cocos2dx
Note: I used 2 lib support load obb by Google to load sound and music
Google Play Licensing Library package
Google Play APK Expansion Library package
Thanks for your support!